# join строк с префиксом и суффиксом

Tags: python, строки

Есть константные строковые префикс и суффикс. Надо соединить список строк, добавляя каждой строке списка эти префикс и суффикс. Можно ли сделать это проще/лучше?

```
prefix = 'a_'
suffix = '_b'

l = ['1', '2', '3']

print(''.join(prefix + s + suffix for s in l))
```

Comment: ваш код выведет a_1_ba_2_ba_3_b, это то, что ожидается?

Comment: У Вас сделано максимально просто. Как вариант: `print(''.join(map(f'{prefix}{{}}{suffix}'.format, l)))`, но это уже похоже на нечитаемый изврат.

Comment: @Jack_oS да, то, это [mre], в коде осмысленные значения

Comment: @МихаилМуругов спасибо, уже сам переписал на f-строки `''.join(f'a_{s}_b' for s in l)`

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать читабельнее:

```
l = ['1', '2', '3']

print(''.join(f'a_{s}_b' for s in l))
```

Comment: только пока prefix и suffix не поменяются )

Comment: @Jack_oS в условии же сказано, что они константные